# ¿Cómo pasar texto con formato de un Windows Form a la aplicación de Word en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, microsoft-office

Tengo un richTextBox en el que escribo texto y le doy color y formato y lo que quiero es que cuando pulse un botón que he programado, me abra la aplicación de Word y me pase el texto que tengo en el richTextBox al Word y que lo pase con el color y formato que le he dado en mi aplicación.

Tengo el siguiente código con el que me abre Word y me pasa el texto que yo tenía en el richTextBox pero el problema es que no me muestra el color y formato que yo tenía en el texto en mi aplicación.

```
colorLetra = new ColorDialog();
// Creamos un objeto de la aplicación de Word.
objWord = new Word.Application();
// Hacemos visible el objeto.
objWord.Visible = true;
// Creamos un documento en Word.
objDocumento = objWord.Documents.Add(Missing.Value);
// Le pasamos contenido al Word.
objWord.Selection.Font.Color = objWord.Selection.Font.Color;
objWord.Selection.TypeText(richTextBox.Text);
```

¿Sabrían decirme porque no me muestra el color y formato en el Word?

Gracias y un saludo!

Comment: básicamente seria un copiar y pegar no? pero cual es la finalidad aparte de eso

Comment: Si, pero que también copie el color y formato que le haya dado al texto desde mi aplicación. Unas pruebas que estoy realizando para poder editar texto y poder pasarlo posteriormente a Word.